Request for Goerli/Sepolia Testnet Ether
I'm currently developing a blockchain application for my internship and need some Goerli or Sepolia testnet Ether to deploy and test my smart contracts. Unfortunately, I don’t have any previous transactions and can't access the usual faucets because they require a prior transaction history.
Could someone please send a small amount of Goerli/Sepolia testnet Ether to my MetaMask wallet address?
Wallet Address: 0x83dFCB658bfA01F59D1B6f62344D988a82Caf6d6
It would really be a huge help! Thanks :)

Goerli is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use Sepolia instead

I've sent 0.5 Sepolia ETH. Also, this post might be helpful to get more Sepolia ETH without requiring any mainnet funds and transaction history.

@SYEDASADKAZMI tysm!!!
